# Java Error: Reached end of file while parsing

Tags: javascript, java, parsing

I keep getting the error: reached end of file while parsing. I can't figure out what is wrong. I assume that I have to close a brace somewhere.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ticketpurchasingprogram
{ 

  public static void main (String[] args)
{  
     string customerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");

     double ticketBaseCost = 10.60;

     int seatSelection = Integer.parseIn( JOption.showInputDialog("Select your seat number")); //There is an additional charge if the seat selected is between seats 56 - 306
      {
        {if (seatSelection == 0 && seatSelection >= 55)
           { 
           if (seatSelection >=56 && seatSelection >= 106)
              {
              if (seatSelection >= 107 && seatSelection <=206)
                 {
                 if (seatSelection >= 207 && seatSelection <= 306)
                    {
                    double seatSelectionCost = 0.00;
                    }
              double seatSelectionCost = 7.45;
                 }
           double seatSelectionCost = 14.30;
              } 
        double seatSelectionCost = 35.16; 
           }       
        }
      }

     ticketSeatCost = ticketBaseCost + seatSlectionCost;

     deliveryMethod = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like your ticket emailed or shipped?");

        {if (deliveryMethod = "emailed")
           {
           if (deliveryMethod = "shipped")
              {
              double convenienceFee = ticketSeatCost * 0.03;
              }
           double convenienceFee = ticketSeatCost * 0.01;
           } 
        } 

     totalCost = ticketSeatCost + convenienceFee;

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "**Eagle Bank Arena Ticket** \n Customer Name: " + customerName + "\n Seat Number: " + seatNumber + "\n Delivery Method: " + deliveryMethod + "\n Ticket Base Cost: " + ticketBaseCost + "\n Seat Cost: " + seatSelectionCost + "\n Convenience Fee: " + convenienceFee + String.format("\n Total Cost $%.2f", totalCost));   

}
```

Comment: It is so hard to read your code. But you are missing one } at the end

Comment: Java != Javascript. Anyway, in a general sense the "reached end of file while parsing" error has an implied "but I still haven't seen the closing bracket or quote I was expecting."

Comment: This needs major refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Could you also verify these conditions again?

```
        if (seatSelection == 0 && seatSelection >= 55)
        { 
            if (seatSelection >=56 && seatSelection >= 106)
            {
                if (seatSelection >= 107 && seatSelection <=206)
                {
                    if (seatSelection >= 207 && seatSelection <= 306)
                    {
                        double seatSelectionCost = 0.00;
                    }
                    double seatSelectionCost = 7.45;
                }
                double seatSelectionCost = 14.30;
            } 
            double seatSelectionCost = 35.16; 
        }
```

These codes will never be executed.
Maybe this is what you meant?

```
        if (seatSelection <= 55)
        { 
            seatSelectionCost = 35.16; 
        }
        else if (seatSelection <= 106)
        {
            seatSelectionCost = 14.30;
        } 
        else if (seatSelection <=206)
        {
            seatSelectionCost = 7.45;
        }
        else if (seatSelection <= 306)
        {
            seatSelectionCost = 0.00;
        }
```

Comment: Since `seatSelection` is an `int`, doing `>=56` in an `else if` following a `<= 55` is redundant. The `else` already ensures that.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many errors in that code, it's difficult knowing where to start.

```
if (seatSelection == 0 && seatSelection >= 55)
```

`seatSelection` cannot both be `== 0` and `>= 55` *at the same time*.

```
if (seatSelection >=56 && seatSelection >= 106)
```

If `seatSelection` is `>= 106`, then by definition it is also `>= 56`, so that test is redundant.

Doesn't matter anyway, since the previous `if` statement cannot be `true`, so it's never executed.

```
{
    double seatSelectionCost = 0.00;
}
```

You declare a *new* variable, initialize it, then exit the definition scope, which means that the variable no longer exists. The code is meaningless.

```
int seatSelection = Integer.parseIn( JOption.showInputDialog("Select your seat number")); //There is an additional charge if the seat selected is between seats 56 - 306
  {
    {
       ...
    }
  }
```

What is the purpose of those braces? They don't do anything.

Sorry, I didn't look at the rest. Too many errors already.

Answer (score -1):

Your curly bracket '}' at the end is missing.
heres the code you need

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ticketpurchasingprogram {

 public static void main (String[] args)
{  
 string customerName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your name");

 double ticketBaseCost = 10.60;

 int seatSelection = Integer.parseIn( JOption.showInputDialog("Select your seat number")); //There is an additional charge if the seat selected is between seats 56 - 306
  {
    {if (seatSelection == 0 && seatSelection >= 55)
       { 
       if (seatSelection >=56 && seatSelection >= 106)
          {
          if (seatSelection >= 107 && seatSelection <=206)
             {
             if (seatSelection >= 207 && seatSelection <= 306)
                {
                double seatSelectionCost = 0.00;
                }
          double seatSelectionCost = 7.45;
             }
       double seatSelectionCost = 14.30;
          } 
    double seatSelectionCost = 35.16; 
       }       
    }
  }

 ticketSeatCost = ticketBaseCost + seatSlectionCost;

 deliveryMethod = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like your ticket emailed or shipped?");

    {if (deliveryMethod = "emailed")
       {
       if (deliveryMethod = "shipped")
          {
          double convenienceFee = ticketSeatCost * 0.03;
          }
       double convenienceFee = ticketSeatCost * 0.01;
       } 
    } 

 totalCost = ticketSeatCost + convenienceFee;

 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "**Eagle Bank Arena Ticket** \n Customer Name: " + customerName + "\n Seat Number: " + seatNumber + "\n Delivery Method: " + deliveryMethod + "\n Ticket Base Cost: " + ticketBaseCost + "\n Seat Cost: " + seatSelectionCost + "\n Convenience Fee: " + convenienceFee + String.format("\n Total Cost $%.2f", totalCost));   
}
}
```

Comment: How is this an improvement? You even mistyped `seatSlectionCost`.

Comment: Hey @Andreas This "improvement" just includes the solution to the error he was getting.
The question is about reach end before parsing. not improve my code

Comment: It's difficult to see what you changed. If all you did was add an extra end-brace at the end, then just saying that would do it. Pasting the entire code (incorrectly too) is not very helpful, especially when it still doesn't compile.